# How Do I Get Out Of This Mess Caused By Power failure While Upgrading To 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, startup

I will start by saying I am an idiot.

I went to bed while upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10. When I woke up I realzed the power had gone. (where I live they 'take light')

Initially, booting up showed me several versions of Ubuntu and their 'safe mode' versions. (I have no idea where they came from).

Selecting one of them brought me to a screen saying

> "Waiting for Network fonfiguration"

Then after a while

> "Booting system without full network configuration"

After waiting for forever, I restarted my system. I now get to a blank black page.

How do I get out of this mess?

Comment: Looking at my previous question here, I realise I had a similar power failure issue when trying to upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04. I should be flogged for not learning from the first time.

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question, when the system lets you just post it as your own answer so it can help the next person, great job!

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I am not sure if I should be answering my question or updating it. Let me know which is the proper thing and I will make the ammendment.

Here is how I fluked it:

When my battery died and I started it again, it showd me a scan disc check screen. After which, it returned the black screen of before.

I pressed all the function keys one after the other then ran my hand all over the keyboard.

I am not sure what particular key triggered a 'DOS looking' log in screen. I inputed my old username and password and it brought me to a 'terminal like' interface.

I did `sudo apt-get upgrade`

and it returned

`dpkg was interrupted you must manually run 'dpkg -- configure - a'`

I then ran that and responded accordingly. It began processing stuff for about 30 mins until I got to the login screen of 11.10

That was how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution in this case may be to either reinstall Ubuntu 11.04 and retry the upgrade, or (better yet) download Ubuntu 11.10 and simply do a fresh install of that.

Comment: I upgraded from within 11.04. Do I just look for another computer and burn 11.10 into a CD? Will my data be safe?

Comment: @Oo Nwoye That's what I would recommend. I'd say your system in its current state won't be repaired by any method other then an install of either 11.04 or 11.10. If you're worried about your data, you can try booting a LiveCD session after burning your CD and mounting your hard drive, then backing up your data as necessary to some external storage device like a USB flash drive. The exception, of course, is any data you already have synchronized with Ubuntu One, which should reappear shortly after setting up Ubuntu One sync on the new install.

Answer (score -1):

There is supposed to be a way to roll back with 11.10, but I haven't tried it yet, and I don't know if it's supposed to work in your scenario. But I suspect it will.

Comment: I have no idea if the installation was complete before power went out. How can I access this 'roll back'?

Comment: I haven't even heard of this, and I don't know how useful this would be if you cannot boot your system into a usable state, anyway.

Comment: I would expect to find the rollback option in the graphical installer, to ensure that you are able to access it if something goes awry during install, but as I said, I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer and it's really vague. Could you add more substance to it?